# Prove or refute $A\subseteq B \wedge B \nsubseteq C \rightarrow A \nsubseteq C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I have to prove or refute $A\subseteq B \wedge B \nsubseteq C \rightarrow A \nsubseteq C$

My refutation: $A = \{1\}, B = \{1, 2\}, C = \{1, 3, 4\}$. Statement does not apply.

Correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that the statement is not true. This is also evident from the following Venn diagram:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have proven, by way of counterexample, that the implication does not hold in general.